# Embedded ember-cli project conflicts with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, requirejs, ember-cli, requirejs-optimizer

I'm trying to embed an EmberJS application into a large portal application which uses extensively the RequireJS library. I'm using ember-cli to build the project. The built application consists of two files, `dist/assets/vendor.js` and `dist/assets/myapp.js`. The EmberJS application works after embedding it but the portal app's javascript breaks.

After some research I've found out the problem is that `vendor.js` defines its own variables `require`, `requirejs`, `requireModule` and `define` which conflict with the website's variables in the global namespace. The `myapp.js` file then contains `define` statements which load the app's modules.

Is there a way to rename these or to put them into some different namespace?

The only solution I came up with was to manually rename the variables within the two `.js` files. This seems to work but it's rather cumbersome and it'd be nice if it could be automated. I have also found out about using RequireJS optimizer but I can't get it to work with the `vendor.js` file.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello @janhink, i know it's been a long time for you, i just stumbled upon your question and want to know what was your solution? what variables you've renamed? because i have the same problem :) Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem, and after much searching I believe I managed to solve it by adding the [ember-derequire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-derequire) addon to my project:

```
ember install ember-derequire
```

That will change all of the 'require' and 'define' statements in your app to 'eriuqer' and 'enifed'.  You can override what it maps to using options (caveat being you have to use something the same length) if you don't like eriuqer and enifed.

In case that doesn't help, the other promising thing I found is that [loader.js](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js) has a noConflict() function, but I couldn't figure out where to put the loader.noConflict() call, or get the build to generate code using alternate names, but maybe it will help you if the first option doesn't work for your situation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It's been a long time and I don't really have a way to test it anymore, but if anyone does and it works, I will accept this as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @[Bjornicus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3499631/bjornicus) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39088322/5056421) wrote, built-in `loader.js`'s `noConflict()` function seems to work correctly. I placed it in main JS file (app.js):

```
window.loader.noConflict({
  define: "emberDefine"
});
```

and `define` wasn't overridden (I import ember app to another app which uses SystemJS). But I've made only few tests, so I don't know if this does not break something later.