# EmberCLI and requirejs

Tags: requirejs, ember-cli

Is it possible to use EmberCLI with an existing requirejs project? I've been searching and I don't see any examples.

EmberCLI exports as AMD...can I just include the EmberCLI part as a require module?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this question: [Embedded ember-cli project conflicts with RequireJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27042145/5056421)

Copied answer:

> built-in loader.js's noConflict() function seems to work correctly. I placed it in main JS file (app.js):
>   `window.loader.noConflict({ define: "emberDefine" });`
>   and define wasn't overridden (I import ember app to another app which uses SystemJS). But I've made only few tests, so I don't know if this does not break something later.